# Trying to join 2 tables in java but i get a Error

Tags: java, sql, join

Im working with Sql and java.
This works in sql:

```
use mybank
Select * from Account
inner join CustomerAccount on accountid = id
where customerid = 18
```

In java i write this:

```
String sql = ("Select * From Account inner join CustomerAccount on accountid = id where customerid =?;");
try (Connection con = myDbManager.getConnection())
{
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, customer.getId());
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

`customer.getId` gives me 18.

but i get this error;

```
Incorrect syntax near '?'.
```

Comment: Does not work and it is there for security reasons :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

You're using [`Statement#executeQuery(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-) which is inherited from `Statement` interface. You should use [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--).

In short, change that line to:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                               ^ parameter-less
```

And remove this `Statement` variable from your code, it will just confuse you and future readers of the code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, customer.getId());
//Statement st = con.createStatement();
  ^ this generates confusion
```

Also, you should remove the semicolon in your SQL statement when executing it form Java:

```
String sql = "Select *"
    + " From Account"
    + " inner join CustomerAccount"
    + " on accountid = id"
    + " where customerid = ?";
```

Comment: I believe you mean to instruct him to use `ps.executeQuery()` (not `st`).

Comment: @JimmyLillegaard don't worry. Accept it once you can.

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Queries in Java don't use the ';':

```
String sql =( "Select * From Account inner join CustomerAccount on accountid = id where customerid =?");
```